# Allow SFTP users read/write access to web document root

Tags: permissions, apache-2.4, sftp

I'm looking for some best practice recommendations on how to implement the following:

I want to create local user accounts which will only have SFTP access and be chrooted into our document root of our website.

I've followed this guide: https://community.rackspace.com/general/f/34/t/5102 on getting the user created and chrooted to the document root, and have enabled rwX permissions using ACLs. The only issue is that when they upload a file, the user is the owner of the file.  All the other documents on the webserver are apache:root for the group/owner.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing it, I would make a new user account, and then change their home directory to the webroot. You will probably have to edit the passwd and shadow file to make it work. Make sure that the webroot is CHMOD for the rw access.

I would discourage you from doing this on a web server unless it is a local network only test server. If it is an actual server, your best bet is to have the ftp root in the `/home/"username"` directory and then copy over the folder.

Comment: Our web server is organization wide with several developers. We all contribute to the same source in a live environment. I'm wanting to move away from samba shares that are directly mapped to the web root. I don't want to have an additional step of having to move content if of several users' folders to publish content. I think having local user accounts all share the same home directory as the web root is risky especially if for some reason the user was deleted along with their home directory.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure that there is a way to automatically change the ownership unless you write a shell script to chown to apache:root at a given interval.